# php array behaving strangely with key value 07 & 08

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array for months

```
$months[01] = 'January';
$months[02] = 'February';
$months[03] = 'March';
$months[04] = 'April';
$months[05] = 'May';
$months[06] = 'June';
$months[07] = 'July';
$months[08] = 'August';
$months[09] = 'September';
$months[10] = 'October';
$months[11] = 'November';
$months[12] = 'December';
```

Now the array does not output correct value for key `07` & `08`.

Try doing `print_r($months)` you will not get any key value `August` and zero key index for `September`.

Though I’m able to solve the problem by removing the leading zero, still I would love to know the reason for same.

Even the PHP editor spots some problem but unable to tell what is the problem.

Thanks

Comment: The worst about how PHP handles this is not that it lets you accidentally use octal when you didn't intend to, but that it evaluates 08 and 09 as 0 silently, which confuses people not aware of octal even more, producing this seemingly random behavior of eating up the value assigned to [08] and associating the value assigned to [09] actually to [0].
PHP's choice to partially parse numbers and when it finds a token stopper just ignores the rest (as does in this example and also when casting a string to an int) is a really bad choice.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Prepending 0 before a number means PHP parses it as an octal value in the same way that prepending 0x causes it to be parsed as a hexadecimal value. Remove the zero, and it will work fine.

```
echo 07; // prints 7
echo 010; // prints 8
```

This is mostly used when specifying unix permissions:

```
chmod("myfile", 0660);
```

Except for that it's rarely something that you'd want to do.

This is described in the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/de/language.types.integer.php).

Answer (score 4):

Generally, putting a leading 0 on a number tells the compiler that you've giving an octal number (base 8, not base 10).

In octal, 8 and 9 don't exist (8 is 010, 9 is 011), so you're confusing php.

If you really want a leading zero, you can use strings for your indexes

Answer (score 3):

PHP will treat numbers with a leading 0 as octal numbers, either drop the leading 0 or put the key values in quotes.

Answer (score 3):

The way you form an [integer literal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) is important.

See the structure for decimal literals?  Notice how a preceeding zero is not part of that pattern?

Either you have to remove the zeros, or treat your array keys as strings

```
$months['01'] = 'January';
$months['02'] = 'February';
// etc...
```

Answer (score 0):

I just realized this after precious minutes of debugging and table head banging.
The problem is that PHP doesn't raise an error or even a warning about having malformed the octal literal integer. It just ignores the part from the error until the end of the literal.
Damn.

PS: Who uses octal numbers? never did, never heard of someone using them for a good reason.
Hexadecimal is great, but octal? damn.
Even for permission I usually do `chmod ugo+rwx` is more straightforward.