# If i create variable with value 020 it become 16?

Tags: php, variables, zero

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [php array behaving strangely with key value 07 & 08](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750781/php-array-behaving-strangely-with-key-value-07-08)

In PHP when i create $myvar = 020 and echo $myvar i get 16 why?

Answer (score 6):

Because if you prefix a number with a 0, PHP assumes that you're working in base 8, and 20 in base 8 is 16 in base 10.

Comment: Why do computer programmers get Halloween and Christmas confused? Because Oct 31 == Dec 25. I'll get my coat, shall I?

Answer (score 1):

Because the starting `0` in `020` tells php its an octal

Some more examples

```
$a = 1234; // decimal number
$a = -123; // a negative number
$a = 0123; // octal number (equivalent to 83 decimal)
$a = 0x1A; // hexadecimal number (equivalent to 26 decimal)
```

Check this php [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php) for more explanation

Answer (score 0):

That is called, integer representation http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php.

```
echo 0b11111; // binary, introduced in PHP 5.4
echo 31; // duh
echo 0x1f; // hexadecimal
echo 037; // octal
```