# PHP removing leading zeros

Tags: php, arrays

I am building an automated email system, as an extension for a membership system I have designed.

Take the following array:

```
array (size=5)
  '002858' => string '<p>These members have expired:</p><p>Adults: None</p><p>Children: Florence Carline</p><p>Disabled Members: None</p>' (length=115)
  '001974' => string '<p>These members have expired:</p><p>Adults: Kelly Hughes, Andrew Hughes</p><p>Children: Alfie Hughes</p><p>Disabled Members: None</p>' (length=134)
  '000033' => string '<p>These members have expired:</p><p>Adults: Kate Shirley</p><p>Children: Rolsin Shirley</p><p>Disabled Members: None</p>' (length=121)
  '000259' => string '<p>These members have expired:</p><p>Adults: Charmaine Walsh, Michael Baxter</p><p>Children: Liam Baxter, George Baxter</p><p>Disabled Members: None</p>' (length=152)
  '000000' => string '<p>These members are expiring in a month:</p><p>Adults: Edward Selby</p><p>Children: None</p><p>Disabled Members: None</p>' (length=122)
```

When I try to read the array back in a foreach loop (one iteration per email) I receive the following error:

```
Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 1974 in C:\wamp\www\subdomains\[host]\controllers\email.class.php on line 145
```

Notice this is the second one down in my array but without its '00'.

I have looked at this: [php array behaving strangely with key value 07 & 08](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4750781/php-array-behaving-strangely-with-key-value-07-08)

So I checked (with is_int()) - The key is a string not int.

Can anyone shed some light on this for me?

EDIT:

**Creation:**

```
foreach($email_list_array['month'] as $key => $ticket) {

    $header[$key] =  "<p>Our records indicate that your pass (ticket number: $key) is expiring or has already expired.</p>";
    $header[$key] .= "<p>Please see the details below</p>";

    if(!isset($message[$key])) {
        $message[$key] = "<p>These members are expiring in a month:</p>";
    } else {
        $message[$key] .= "<p>These members are expiring in a month:</p>";
    }

    $message[$key] .= "<p>Adults: $adults</p>";
    $message[$key] .= "<p>Children: $children</p>";
    $message[$key] .= "<p>Disabled Members: $disabled</p>";

}
```

**This is where I did the array dump**

```
var_dump($message);
```

**Test Output:**

```
foreach($message as $key => $value) {

    $message_header = $header[$key];
    $message = $message[$key];

    echo $message_header;
    echo $message;
    echo "<br>";

}
```

Comment: Show us some code. If that string offset error is not just a coincidence, then that means you're using your array key as a parameter to `substr` or some other string function.

Comment: Possible to see the loop code?

Comment: you are changing your variable $message from array to string: $message = $message[$key];

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the name of variable $message inside foreach:

```
$messageXXX = $message[$key];
echo $messageXXX;
```

Comment: Leg-end. I thought it was something simple.

Comment: But how does this convert integer 1974 to string "001974" while trying to access the array posted above?

Comment: It isnt. If it's wrapped in single quotes, it sees a string. At no point does it interpret what is in there as an int.

Comment: Ahh I see, initially it did interpret "001974" as int beeing 1974 and then when accessing the array it fails due to missing zeros. However in case you use "001974" always as string it wont be interpreted as int and thus the array access is fine - right?

Comment: what are you talking about? :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess the array is accessed as integer not as string. So you should convert the integer to string.

Please note there is a difference between access by integer and access by string!

```
$arrayX = array( "A", "X" );
$arrayY = array( "0012"=> "A", "0001"=>"b" );


print_r( $arrayX );

print_r( $arrayY);

echo "array X ". $arrayX[1];  // returns "X"
echo "array Y".$arrayY["0012"];  // returns "A"
echo "array Y ".$arrayY[12];       // should also return "A"
```

The output is as follows

```
Array
(
    [0] => A
    [1] => X
)
Array
(
    [0012] => A
    [0001] => b
)
XA
Notice: Undefined offset: 12 in /test.php on line 14
```

In your case you also need to add the leading zeros with something like

```
$value = 12; // integer
$str = sprintf("%04d",$value);  // now $str = "0012"
echo "array Y ".$arrayY[ $str ];       // now returns "A"
```

Comment: understood. I have checked $key with `is_int($key)` and it returns as a string.

Comment: I will double check this

Comment: not only convert it to string but also add the leading "0" zeros!

Comment: Some passes have 3 or 4 preceding

Comment: sprintf("%04d", ...) fills in zeros as needed. the 4 describes we need 4 digits. So when converting "3" it returns "0003" if you convert "444" it only adds one zero to "0444".

Answer (score 1):

Part of your problem is you are assigning a value to `$message` in your loop, but `$message` was your input variable. This is making PHP do what it is doing. It also appears that your are trying to grab the same keys from two different arrays.  Is this correct?

Anyhow take a look at the following:

```
foreach($message as $key => $value) {

    $message_header = $header[$key];
    $messageText = $message[$key];

    echo $message_header;
    echo $messageText;
    echo "<br>";

}
```

This would hopefully show what changes you need in your test to stop that error from happening.

Comment: Got it. Thanks guys, I had tunnel vision!